# Change class and color of Font Awesome icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

When I click on the icon I simply want to change its class and color. This is my code below

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
 alert("Icon clicked");
  // on click please change icon and color to red
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```

On click I want to change the **li class** to  `class="fa fa-address-book"`  and color of icon to red.

Comment: nice try .. an empty jquery block ...

Comment: Please show an example of what you have tried so far. A comment saying "//on click please change icon and color to red" isn't suitable

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do something like the following:

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
  alert("Icon clicked");
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-address-book');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```

Comment: and how to change the color to red ?

Comment: @user2828442 with css method

Comment: ...may be: .toggleClass('fa-camera-retro fa-address-book red')

Comment: @gaetanoM yes it's possible

Comment: @OmiD Right for you: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
 $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-camera-retro').addClass('fa-address-book').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the element with `find()`. Then use `removeClass()` to remove existing classes and add classes with `addClass()`. You can use `.css()` to set the style:

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
  alert("Icon clicked");
  $(this).find('i.fa.fa-camera-retro').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-address-book');
  $(this).find('i').css({color: 'red'});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```

Comment: if there are 2 i's in the div, it erases that, how can it only change the class of the clicked one only

Comment: @user2828442, then you have to target the existing class of the element. I have updated the answer....please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. remove the existing class - `removeClass()`
2. add a new class - `addClass()`
3. add color css to the icon - `css()`

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
 alert("Icon clicked");
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-camera-retro').addClass('fa-address-book').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".sim-row-edit-icon").click(function(){
  $(".sim-row-edit-icon > i").removeClass('fa-camera-retro').addClass('fa-address-book');
  $(".sim-row-edit-icon > i").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="sim-row-edit-icon">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
</div>
```